# Regtest createmultisig Error: Invalid public Key?

Tags: multi-signature, bitcoin-cli, regtest

As shown below, I generated 3 new addresses (Legacy I believe) in RegTest. I then try to create a multsig address from exactly these 3 addresses. What am I doing wrong, or is this unavailable in Regtest?

'''**$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress**
2NFjbToRhpR2Lrx3VyP8rZ86XhZhofqWHBk

**$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress**
2NAqXJMEFzEbhNyy9xRiHHcwWNCyFddFfXH

**$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress**
2NEyDQfb85jRExQUnj4wC7fkFh5T1rt5zFk

**$ bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 "[\"2NFjbToRhpR2Lrx3VyP8rZ86XhZhofqWHBk\", \"2NAqXJMEFzEbhNyy9xRiHHcwWNCyFddFfXH\",\"2NEyDQfb85jRExQUnj4wC7fkFh5T1rt5zFk\"]"**

error code: -5

error message:
Invalid public key: 2NFjbToRhpR2Lrx3VyP8rZ86XhZhofqWHBk
.'''

Answer (score 2):

Addresses are not public keys. You cannot give `createmultisig` addresses because it cannot know what public keys your addresses refer to, if any. To get the public keys, you need to first do `getaddressinfo <address>`. That will give you a pubkey you can give to `createmultisig`.

Answer (score 1):

The `createmultisig` RPC takes as input public keys, not addresses. As you created those addresses yourself, their public keys are in your wallet. `createmultisig` however is a utility RPC (which operates independently of the wallet), so it has no access to that information.

You can call the `getaddressinfo` wallet RPC on those addresses to obtain their public keys.